# Rotated ( 90 degrees ) root ViewGroup

Tags: android

I am trying to create ViewGroup based on FrameLayout that might be rotated 90 degrees CW / CCW and it still will be working correctly

So far my results are not so sucesful. So far it looks like that ( left side before rotation, right after; sorry for bright red )

[image: Rotated ViewGroup]

**Layout** for Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.TestProject.RotatedFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00F"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RotatedFrameLayout**

```
public class RotatedFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private boolean firstMeasure = true;

    public RotatedFrameLayout( Context context ) {
        super( context );
        init();
    }

    public RotatedFrameLayout( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( context, attrs );
        init();
    }

    public RotatedFrameLayout( Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle ) {
        super( context, attrs, defStyle );
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setRotation( 90f );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec ) {
        super.onMeasure( heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec );
    }
}
```

Some extra info

- I don't want to use Animation rotation because buttons aren't clickable that way
- I don't want to use landscape mode because in landscape on screen navigation buttons took a lot of space on Nexus 7 ( this is the main reason why I am trying to greate that rotated
- It seems that only left and right side of the screen are out of bounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite hard to do and I think it is not worth doing. But if you really want to do this you need:

- pass to ViewGroup correct size dimentions (swap width and height).
- rotate ViewGroup canvas 90 degrees. 
  At this point everything should look fine, but touch events not working properly.
- intercept all touch events and swap x and y. Then pass fixed events to ViewGroup.

I dont have any code samples and have never seen any ) This way should work, we did scale transformations with fragments where we had to fix touch events coordinates when fragment was scaled.

I havent tested it heavily but this works:

```
public class RotatedFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

public RotatedFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public RotatedFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public RotatedFrameLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
private void init() {
    setPivotX(0);
    setPivotY(0);
    setRotation(90f);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setTranslationX(getMeasuredHeight());
}
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Hi, thanks for tips. I swapped dimensions and rotated it already, tried that in various combinations, so far without success but at the moment code above does not break button on touch behaviour ( it is still clickable ). More problems with proper sizing. Is it worth it? It is idea to do something with on screen navigation buttons that took a lot of space in landscape on smaller devices :/ on 10 inch tablets this is not such a issue.

Comment: I haven't seen setRotation method yet... since API11. I'll see how it works. We support old android versions, so we did use it.

Comment: If you want to support **RTL** layout direction, in onMeasure() use something like:
`if (isRtl) { setTranslationX(getMeasuredWidth()); } else { setTranslationX(getMeasuredHeight()); }`